# Quantum dimension in the Drinfeld center

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, modular-tensor-categories, drinfeld-center

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a spherical tensor category. It is known that the Drinfeld center of $\mathcal{C}$ is modular (and therefore also spherical), see for example, [Corollary 8.20.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z6XLDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA243) in [1]. Recall the notion of dimension in spherical tensor categories obtained by taking the quantum trace of the identity.

**Question:** For a given object $Z = (X,\gamma)$ in the Drinfeld center is there a simple way to express the dimension $d(Z)$ in terms of $X$ and $\gamma$?

[1] *Etingof, Pavel; Gelaki, Shlomo; Nikshych, Dmitri; Ostrik, Victor*, [**Tensor categories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/surv/205), Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 205. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-1-4704-2024-6/hbk). xvi, 343 p. (2015). [ZBL1365.18001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1365.18001)..

Comment: Isn't the spherical structure you put on the Drinfeld center "equal" to that of $\mathcal{C}$? I.e. $d(Z)=d(X)$?

Comment: You are quite correct, this can be seen by doing Exercise 7.13.6. in the reference I provided. I feel a bit silly asking just a trivial question!